# Are other manufacturers allowed to produce an oxylobactor formigenes probiotic?

Tags: patent-infringement, international, application

In reference to the patent: [WO2015002588A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2015002588A1)

What is the scope of this application?

Can it stop other manufacturers from creating anything containing the supplement?

I heard in Asia there is a supplement containing this strain, and I'm not sure whether they could be infringing on this.

Answer (score 1):

An application is not a patent.  An application cannot stop anyone from doing anything.  Furthermore, the claims of an application may change during prosecution.

What if the application *does* become a patent with the claims as currently written?

Well, is "an oxylobactor formigenes probiotic" a "secretagogue derived from oxalate degrading bacteria" as recited in Claim 1?

Focus on the claims.  Is every item in a particular claim found in a potentially infringing product?  I don't know this technical field, so I can't comment further.